# Will closing windows explorer save the battery?

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-xp

If i am working on a single program and i don't want to keep the others program running. I 
open up the task manager and closes the "Explorer.exe" file.
Will it help me saving energy or my battery's power?

Comment: Different versions of windows, and different processors save power differently. On my current laptop, turning off the sound makes an appreciable difference to battery life, but that may not be true on another chipset, or even a differently designed laptop of the same era.

Answer (score 3):

It will not make a significant difference.

When idle, Windows Explorer consumes virtually no CPU time.  As such, doing so will have no practical bearing on power consumption or battery life.

Comment: not only that, depending on background service on programs, Windows will just reopen it

Answer (score 1):

It won't make a difference.
Only killing programs that use a lot of CPU helps, the rest you can neglect. Look in Task Manager (sort on CPU usage) if any apply. Real power saving benefits are on the hardware level:

- Turn down screen brightness
- Disable Wifi and Bluetooth if you don't need them
- Unplug unused devices (e.g USB)
- Experiment with the power settings in the configuration panel with regard to powering down the screen, hard disk etc.
- Experiment with the time settings before the PC goes into sleep or hibernate mode. If you regularly walk away from your machine this may help.

Answer (score 0):

Explorer.exe require few RAM but almost zero Processor efficiency while ideal, you can close some extra programs like **dwm.exe** and Configure the Laptop's brightness to minimum of your level.
you can use the TuneUp Utility or Similar application which provide the options like
Economy mode/Standard mode/Turbo mode for Power saving as well as Higher processing.

beside that you can also stop the wallpaper sliding, sidebar and process like servers, mute the sound, and some programs like VMware require a services to be run every time, you can disable those too.
Go to Administrator tools> Services to see more.